# How to determine COM object size in memory?

Tags: c++, com

I have MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodeList interface.
I can find the common length of all MSXML2::IXMLDOMNode-s from this list using such code:

```
MSXML2::IXMLDOMNode* pDOMXMLNode = 0;
BSTR NodeText;
ULONG lValueSize = 0;
ULONG lCommonLength = 0;
while(pDOMXmlNodeList->nextNode(&pDOMXMLNode)== S_OK)
{      
 pDOMXMLNode->get_xml(&NodeText);      
 CString strNode(NodeText);
 lValueSize += strNode.GetLength();      
}    
lCommonLength += lValueSize;
```

It is good, but it is not what i want to find: i want to determine object instance's size in memory.
Is there a way to make it in C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can determine exact size of COM object. However, you can use the following trick to determine approximate size of COM objects.

```
//First determine how much memory your program is currently using. 
//Say it is currently `m1`

//allocate COM object

//Now again, determine how much memory your program is using
//Say it is m2

//COM object size = m2 - m1
```

Microsoft provides some API to determine the memory state of the program. Here is how you apply the above technique to  Microsoft API:

```
_CrtMemState m1;
_CrtMemCheckpoint( &m1 );

 //COM object creation

_CrtMemState m2;
_CrtMemCheckpoint( &m2 );

_CrtMemState difference;
_CrtMemDifference(&difference, &m1,&m2);
```

The object `difference` tells the size of COM object. You can print its value as:

```
_CrtMemDumpStatistics( &difference );
```

Or, you can further analyse the object `difference` which is of type `_CrtMemState` defined  as:

```
//crtdbg.h

struct _CrtMemBlockHeader;
typedef struct _CrtMemState
{
    struct _CrtMemBlockHeader * pBlockHeader;
    size_t lCounts[_MAX_BLOCKS];
    size_t lSizes[_MAX_BLOCKS];
    size_t lHighWaterCount;
    size_t lTotalCount;
} _CrtMemState;
```

Read the documentation at MSDN:

- [Memory State Comparison](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tz9b54s%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Depending on how MSXML was compiled, its memory usage may or may not be accounted for by the CRT. Also thus assumes another thread is not doing memory allocation/freeing at the same time. And your program can easily contain threads not of your creation.

Answer (score 1):

COM doesn't provide a way to know the size of an object. In a way it can't - if the object is in another process, do you want to know the size of the stub in your process or the size of the actual object in the other process?

You can approximate it by creating a large number of instances and using memory monitoring to see how that changes the overall application memory footprint.

Answer (score 1):

Is it *instance size* you're after, or the total memory footprint of the object? It's rather important to understand the distinction.

If the instance contains a pointer to dynamic memory, that's only 4 to 8 bytes of instance data, but the memory block pointed at could be as big as anything. And like others said, there's no reliable way to know either. Instance size could be muddled my marshaling. Memory foorprint could be muddled by private heaps, memory sharing and such.

COM itself provides no mechanism for that. C++ doesn't either - the COM server you're talking may not even be written in C++ (although in case of MSXML, it probably is).

For a specific version and build of the MSXML library, the Microsoft symbol server may provide some insight into implementation details; for example, it might give you instance size. However, this doesn't scale to production - do you really want to ship a homemade debugger that downloads the symbols for MSXML and parses them on the user's machine?

As for the memory footprint, then process memory consumption snapshots are your friend, and even those should be taken with a grain of salt size of something very big.